# Laravel Angular how to filter date on Carbon String?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, laravel, time

how can you filter date on a JSON time like created_at like 2016-02-29 19:20:00 ?

The Angular filter only works on timestamp.
How can i change the output to the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to do manipulate the `created_at` time or w/e time. I would highly suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this.

Few examples from their page.

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 28th 2016, 2:17:50 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Sunday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Feb 28th 16
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
moment().format();
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me, below my solution:

**In Json:**

```
data[i].itemDate = data[i].itemDate.replace(/(.+) (.+)/, "$1T$2Z")
data[i].itemDate = new Date(data[i].itemDate);
```

Now you can use Angular filter

Answer (score 0):

if you use `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` time format you must be shure in a itemDate in UTC time zone. If your itemDate in GMT+0200 (for example) just drop "Z" from end, it helps to me :)

```
itemDate.replace(/(.+) (.+)/, "$1T$2")
```